# g++ with std::exclusive_scan (c++17)

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, clang++, libstdc++

Is `std::exclusive_scan` implemented with `libstdc++`? I'm trying to use the function but I'm getting compilation error saying `std::exclusive_scan` is not found. [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Sjrtnuwn3heP8NqM) is the sample code. With clang compiler I'm able to run the code without `stdlib=libc++` option. I've included the correct header file (`<numeric>`) and compiling using `std=c++17` flag.

Comment: What version of gcc?

Comment: Your provided link compiles just fine for me with output `1 2 4 7 11` which is correct.

Comment: On wandbox (and on local machine), I'm using gcc-8.3.0. As I said, Clang7.0.0 compiles fine on wandbox without libc++ option.

Comment: The link I provided before, use clang compiler. Switch to gcc 8.3.0 and compilation fails. Here's the link for failure. https://wandbox.org/permlink/dDrG2BYn0YsF7fH2

Comment: Interestingly, gcc-9 seems to have the parallel version but not the sequential one...

Comment: It just got added to gcc today, so it will be in gcc-10 at least.

Comment: Fails for me in clang version 7.0.1-8+deb10u2 actually.